# Rails' form_for_filterrific doesn't work in production env (but works in dev. env)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, filterrific

I'm using filterrific 4.0.0 (but I also tried 4.0.1 and 2.0.5) in rails 4.2.10 and ruby 2.3.0 and all filterrific's options (which I use) work for me correctly in development environment (e.g. filterrific_sorting_link or form_for_filterrific).
Unfortunately all form_for_filterrific with "select" (example below) don't work in production environment (filterrific_sorting_links are OK). 
There is one (observed by me) an exception when these "selects" work in production environment - when I am redirected by some other (POST action) form (in controller by rails [action "create"]) to the page with these "selects". 
But when I simply render all my pages with these "selects" these buttons don't work at all - nothing happens after clicking at them.

Maybe it is something with asset pipeline (this is a major difference between these two environments - I had in the past some troubles with application.js when something using jQuery was working in dev. and wasn't working in prod. env.)?
Should maybe something be added there related to filteriffic?

```
<%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f| %>
    <div>
        <%= f.select(:with_player_club, 
            @filterrific.select_options[:with_player_club],
            { include_blank: t('all_teams') }, class: 'form-control') %>
    </div>
    <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
<% end %>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.
Regards!

Comment: P.S. I have in application.js a line: //= require filterrific/filterrific-jquery

Comment: Try putting your application into production mode locally, precompile the assets, all that production stuff. See if it's still happening.

Another thing to check is if you have accidently included the javascript twice. I had a problem with Bootstrap awhile back where things wouldn't work in production, and it was because I had included the JavaScript twice.

Answer (score 0):

I did all necessary production stuff once again (including precompilation) and... everything works now.

I think that before something went wrong with precompilation of filterrific's spinner which is being triggered when "selects" are used.

Repeat precompilation - this is the answer.